# GET URL string bad encoding

Tags: string, symfony, character-encoding, get

I was trying to get xml code into string. Here is an example:

```
 URL: .../importarxml?enviosXml=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>+<lista>+<envio>+<REFERENCIA>XXXXXX</REFERENCIA>+<CODIGO>XXXXX</CODIGO>+<CLIENTE>OCAÑA</CLIENTE>+<FCARGA>13/12/2013</FCARGA>+<LCARGA>XXX</LCARGA>+<DESTINATARIO>XXXXX</DESTINATARIO>+<FENTREGA>18/12/2013</FENTREGA>+<LENTREGA>PARIS</LENTREGA>+<MATRICULA>XXXXXX</MATRICULA>+<BULTOS>2</BULTOS>+<PESO>1302</PESO>+<OBSERVACIONES></OBSERVACIONES>+</envio>+</lista>
```

That's my code to get parameters from URL in my Controller in symfony:

```
class EnviosController extends Controller{

 public function importarxmlAction(){
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $xml = $request->query->get('enviosXml'); // $xml get bad characters
    ld($xml); --> (Displays $xml string content. Show bad characters)
    //For example 'OCAÑA'-->'OCAï¿½A'
    (ldd-->LadybugBundle)

    $utf8_1 = utf8_decode($xml);        
    $utf8_2 = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $utf8_1);
    $utf8_2 = mb_convert_encoding($utf8_2, 'ISO-8859-1','UTF-8');        
    ld($utf8_2);  // Display $utf8_2 content  
    ...
 }
```

}

I tryed utf8_decode(),iconv() and mb_convert_encoding() but didn't help me. I don't know what else to do, if anyone could help me I'll appreciate it.

Thanks.

P.S: Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: what the hell is ldd?

Comment: Please provide a concise and complete code, keep it simple, also, try to provide the input data

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea to pass a whole XML in the url, by the GET method. Your url is not even escaped to be used as url string...

You should either give the reference of an existing file by its id/name or upload it by a form (method POST)

Then check the encoding of your file.

Comment: This solution could be correct but forget about passing a whole XML in the URL. If I try .../importarxml?enviosXml=ocaña I have same issue